# How do I reset LDAP pagination in PHP8?

Tags: php, ldap

Up from PHP8.0+, the `ldap_control_paged_result()` and `ldap_control_paged_result_response()` functions are no longer available.

Previously, it was possible to set the page size back to default with a simple call:

```php
ldap_control_paged_result($ldap, 0);
```

What is the equivalent in PHP 8? There's no `ldap_result()` function to pass the **Control** object.

Comment: You should use the function `ldap_search()` in combination with the parameter `controls`: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ldap-search.php, https://www.php.net/manual/en/ldap.controls.php. To parse the parameters you can use `ldap_parse_result`: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ldap-parse-result.php

Comment: You mean I should run an extra `ldap_search()` after I processed all the returned entries? With an empty query or something?

Comment: no, you should use it instead of `ldap_control_paged_result`. You can look also on the site https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ldap-control-paged-result.php where it's written: "Warning
This function has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 7.4.0, and REMOVED as of PHP 8.0.0. Instead the controls parameter of ldap_search() should be used. See also LDAP Controls for details.".

Comment: Maybe wasn't clear, but I **am** using the `controls` object to set the page size. My question is how to **reset** the paging, so the next call in my persistent ldap object will not use the previous value? Otherwise, I might get an LDAP error on the next query within the same request.

Comment: Sorry, then I don't know, maybe you check `php.net/manual/en/function.ldap-parse-result.php` again, to parse the results?
Sorry, I don't use LDAP, so I can't help any further.

Comment: I've read the manual but not really helpful about how to handle multiple queries during a request. Maybe I need to set the page size for each control object I call. Thanks for the effort though.